# motion blur equivalent for glAccum and vertex buffer object (VBO)?

Tags: opengl, vbo

I was wondering what the equivalent for `glAccum(GL_MULT, decayFactor)` and Frame Buffer objects (FBO) is. Does an equivalent exist or do I need to implement something myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "equivalent" is "implement it with shaders" ;) It's not that hard to do.

Comment: ah, ok. I still didn't figure out what shaders are for - can you maybe point me to some good documentation? thanks!

Comment: @memyself: "What shaders are for"? They're for replacing most of the stuff you use: vertex transformations, all that ridiculous `glTexEnv` stuff, etc. If you want to learn about modern shader-based graphics programming, I'm [writing a lengthy eBook on the subject](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/). It's for beginners, so it'll teach stuff you probably already know.

Comment: I guess you mean this chapter: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut03%20A%20Better%20Way.html ?

Comment: @memyself: Actually I meant the entire thing. You lack an understanding of how shaders work; the book will teach you how they work (among other things). What you will not get is an explanation of how to replicate accumulation buffers with shaders.